# Java - How to reference the body and inputed parameter inside a method?

Tags: java, merge, pass-by-reference

Apologies if the terminology is not correct. Let's say I have a method called "merge". I have an object called "a" and another called "b". If I choose to call this method to merge "a" and "b", I believe I should do something like a.merge(b). My question is, how would I reference both "a" and "b" values inside of a method?

For example:

```
Sequence a = ...;
Sequence b = ...;
Sequence c = a.merge(b);
public Sequence merge(Sequence other){
...
}
```

Inside of the merge method, what would be the proper way to refer to the the body (a) and argument (b)? Very new to java, therefore apologies on using the wrong terminology. Any resource I could reference for this problem would also be helpful.

Comment: In the method, you use `this` for what the method is called on (`a`), and `other` for the parameter because that's the name you gave it.

Comment: what exactly you are going to do with merge ?

Comment: Why not make a method that takes two sequences? The way you would use something like `a.merge(b)` would be if the sequence class had a merge method then you would use the instance variables and the passed in object.

Answer (score 1):

Your `other` `Sequence` is `b`, while `this` refers to the object itself, which is `a`.

```
public Sequence merge(Sequence other){
    this.something; //refers to A, the object on which the call was made
    other.something; //refers to B, the object passed as a parameter
}
```

This naturally assumes a call like the one you have:

```
a.merge(b);
```